# How to implement static local variable in go

Tags: go, static, closures, local

I'm in the learning curve with go. I like like :-)

Well, I would like to implement such a **static local variable** to avoid to declare a global one. But I struggle with closure. I would like to print a message only the first time the function is called, and not the other times.

Here is my code

```golang
func append(path string, vars Vars) {

    // raise a warning only once
    func() (func()){
        var f bool
        return func(){
            if len(vars["hostlurl"]) == 0 && !f {
                f = true
                fmt.Println("Warning: missing hosturl.")
            }
        }
    }()

    // append
    ...

}
```

In this code the local code `if len(...` is never called

Is there a way to avoid to add a global variable?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You'd have to make append a variable with the closure as its value: https://go.dev/play/p/6CK_LWB96wf

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva, your proposal is not exactly what I was looking but it works fine and is an acceptable solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

There are no "static local variables" in Go.

If a function needs a state, you have numerous options. Try all on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/DXll593Y9sD).

#### You may use a package level variable:

```
var state bool

func f1() {
    if !state {
        state = true
        fmt.Println("f1() first")
    }
    fmt.Println("f1() called")
}
```

Testing:

```
f1()
f1()
// Output
f1() first
f1() called
f1() called
```

#### Or pass the (pointer to) state as an argument:

```
func f2(state *bool) {
    if !*state {
        *state = true
        fmt.Println("f2() first")
    }
    fmt.Println("f2() called")
}
```

Testing:

```
var state bool
f2(&state)
f2(&state)
// Output
f2() first
f2() called
f2() called
```

#### Or you may use a method and the state may be stored in the receiver:

```
type foo struct {
    state bool
}

func (v *foo) f3() {
    if !v.state {
        v.state = true
        fmt.Println("foo.f3() first")
    }
    fmt.Println("foo.f3() called")
}
```

Testing:

```
v := foo{}
v.f3()
v.f3()
// Output
foo.f3() first
foo.f3() called
foo.f3() called
```

#### Or use [`sync.Once`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Once) which is also concurrency safe:

```
var f2Once sync.Once

func f4() {
    f2Once.Do(func() {
        fmt.Println("f4() first")
    })
    fmt.Println("f4() called")
}
```

Testing:

```
f4()
f4()
// Output
f4() first
f4() called
f4() called
```

#### Or return a *closure* that refers to a local variable:

```
func f5() func() {
    var state bool
    return func() {
        if !state {
            state = true
            fmt.Println("f5() first")
        }
        fmt.Println("f5() called")
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
fret := f5()
fret()
fret()
// Output
f5() first
f5() called
f5() called
```

#### You may also use a function variable, assigning a *closure* to it:

```
var f6 = func() func() {
    var state bool
    return func() {
        if !state {
            state = true
            fmt.Println("f6() first")
        }
        fmt.Println("f6() called")
    }
}()
```

Testing:

```
f6()
f6()
// Output
f6() first
f6() called
f6() called
```

#### You may also use a [method value](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values) as a function:

```
type bar struct {
    state bool
}

func (v *bar) f7() {
    if !v.state {
        v.state = true
        fmt.Println("foo.f7() first")
    }
    fmt.Println("foo.f7() called")
}

var f7 = (&bar{}).f7
```

Testing:

```
f7()
f7()
// Output
f7() first
f7() called
f7() called
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer @icza. I would like to avoid to use a global variable. Is there a way to make `func f3()` a local function?

Comment: @miky I edited the answer adding a new option, it's now `f5()`. What do you mean local function? The function must be returned to capture the local `state` variable for it to work.